# Change android listview element height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

**Problem:** I want to reduce row height of a single list view item. I don't know exactly it is possible or not.

Here is the codes I used

```
<ListView
  android:id="@+id/listView1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="338dp"
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:layout_y="22dp" >
</ListView>
```

java code

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayTest);

list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I meant single row in the list view

Comment: its ok. but now what you want to do exactly?

Comment: Are you sure that this is good idea? FYI, Android devices comes in different resolution so be sure.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake! It should be the height.

Comment: In my opinion use custom Adapater.

Comment: What you want to implement exactly? Be more specific.

Comment: Can I change height from the XML ?

Comment: @Paresh Mayani I want to reduce row height of a single list view item. I don't know exactly it is possible or not.

Comment: @Grant yes thats the thing you should have mentioned in your question.  Now, you can define **custom adapter for your listview**

Answer (score 4):

As you want to reduce height of every items of ListView, you have to define **Custom adapter with custom layout for your listview.**

Check this:

1. [Customizing Android ListView Items with Custom ArrayAdapter](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)
2. [Android ListView and ListActivity](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: @Grant you can go through `ListView` category on my blog as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the width of the whole width then just change the value for

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

to whatever you want for instance

```
android:layout_width="100dp"
```

otherwise check out [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter) on how to create a custom adapter and create your own layout xml for the list items

Comment: Sorry for the mistake! It should be the height.

Comment: ok so go with option be the tutorial, does that work for you?

Comment: It does not change the elements height,instead changes the whole listview.